# Question about Perl logger - Log::Log4perl

Tags: perl, logging

I need to configure Log::Log4perl to make the following:

1. Some type of messages write to file only.
2. Another type of messages write to file and print to screen as well.

Answer (score 3):

Set up [categories](http://p3rl.org/Log::Log4perl#Categories) for your types of messages. [Message duplication](http://p3rl.org/Log::Log4perl::FAQ#My_application_is_already_logging_to_a_file._How_can_I_duplicate_all_messages_to_also_go_to_the_screen?) is even a FAQ.